# Es posible bloquear un bypass vpn/proxy?

Tags: proxy, vpn

Tengo un script en mi web que bloquea a usuarios que usen un vpn/proxy para evitar visitas raras, pero al parecer existe también una forma de burlar con un bypass, ¿existe forma de desarrollar un "antibypass"?

Answer (score 0):

En mi experiencia te digo (puedo incluso estar errado): La mayoría de los bypass se sustentan en:

1. malas configuraciones en las redes, sistemas o aplicaciones.
2. Bugs de aplicaciones.
3. Errores de diseño (como los que tienen los estándar TCP/IP y OSI).

Creo que lo mejor que se puede hacer hoy en día, es tener actualizado los sistemas y aplicaciones con los últimos parches de seguridad. Por otro lado, uno como programador tiene la **responsabilidad** de ejercer buenas practicas de seguridad en el código. También te puedes perfeccionar en estos aspectos, con la tecnología que sea que uses para programar.

Actualmente, existen varias formas de mejorar la seguridad, como con aplicaciones WAF que protegen el tráfico web con "modelos de tráfico".

Los bypass siempre están por adelante. Siempre va a haber exploits, errores de diseño, etc. Esta matemáticamente comprobado. Las cuestiones de bypass-antibypass es una guerra sin fin.

Si lo que te interesa es proteger la capa de aplicación, lo mejor que puedes hacer es, como puse arriba, tener actualizada las aplicaciones y paquetes que utilices, perfeccionarte en seguridad a la hora de programar.

Si deseas ir más allá (acá ya entran otros roles), puedes estudiar muy bien como funcionan las otras capas donde puede haber fugas de seguridad (transporte y red), y crear scripts que pongan en vista esas vulnerabilidades.

Saludos

Comment: Supongo que aquí juegan cosas como el pentesting y demás

Comment: Claro si. Las pruebas de ataques se pueden realizar y son distintas en cada capa (aplicacion, transporte, red, etc). Normalmente a los desarroladores se les hace controles de calidad, para que cumplan con ciertos estandares.